# trait with output-type Tuple mismatches other Traits Type, which is the same tuple

Tags: rust

I'm using a not-changeable lib (Their) and own (My) code.
I try to use a tuple-output from 'Their' function as input in 'My' function and it doesnt compile because 'My' function
`expected MyCenter::Input, found TheirShadow::Output`

Do you have insights how to fix or work around that issue?

Thanks!

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=88f7d9d070d2337178d7225314a19020)

```
// All objects which are called 'Their...' are a lib which cant be changed
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct TheirPoint {
    x: i32,
    y: i32
}


// All objects which are called 'My...' are own code
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MyDrawing<T> {
    graph: T
}


/*
'MyCalculate' Trait for MyDrawing has a calculate function, which  
  1st draws 'TheirShadow' of 'TheirPoint'
    the output is a output type of a trait, which is defined for 'TheirPoint' as
    (TheirPoint, TheirPoint)
    
  2nd it centers with 'MyCenter'
    'MyCenter' center() needs a input, which is defined for 'TheirPoint' as
    (TheirPoint, TheirPoint), which is exactly the output 

    -> it doesnt compile, because 
    expected MyCenter::Input, found TheirShadow::Output

*/

impl<T> MyCalculate for MyDrawing<T> 
where T: TheirShadow + MyCenter
{
    fn calculate(&self, distance: i32) {
        let shadowOfGraph = self.graph.cast_shadow(distance);
        self.graph.center(shadowOfGraph)
    }
}
        

pub trait MyCalculate {
    fn calculate(&self, distance: i32); 
}


impl TheirShadow for TheirPoint {
    type Output = (TheirPoint, TheirPoint);

    fn cast_shadow(self, distance: i32) -> Self::Output {
        let end = TheirPoint { x: self.x+distance, y: self.y+distance };
        
        (self, end)
    }
}


pub trait TheirShadow {
    type Output;
    fn cast_shadow(self, distance: i32) -> Self::Output;
}



pub trait MyCenter {
    type Input;
    fn center(&self, input: Self::Input);
}

impl MyCenter for TheirPoint {
    type Input = (TheirPoint, TheirPoint);

    fn center(&self, input: Self::Input) {
        // expecting tuple of points
        println!("input {:?}", input);
        println!("Result of Calculation");   
        
    }
}


fn main()
{
    let p = TheirPoint {
        x: 3,
        y: 3
    };
    
    let d = MyDrawing {
        graph: p
    };
    
    let xx = d.calculate(4);
    println!("{:?}", xx);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barring the two small fixes (making the struct `TheirPoint` and the type parameter `T` `Copy`) needed to make the code compilable, you need to specify that the impl of `MyCenter` and `TheirShadow` for `T` specify the same associated types. In other words, `<T as MyCenter>::Input` must equal `<T as TheirShadow>::Output`. Without this specification, there is no way for the compiler to know if the type of the value returned by `self.graph.cast_shadow` (i.e. the type of the binding`shadowOfGraph`) is the same as the type of the parameter to `self.graph.center`.

This can be done by adding an additional type parameter `S` to the `MyCalculate` impl to hold the type that both these associated types must be assigned to:

```
impl<S, T> MyCalculate for MyDrawing<T> 
    where T: TheirShadow<Output=S> + MyCenter<Input=S>
```

[Rust playground (with the `Copy` fixes)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1bd8e60810a4e73454b23884d9bf91f7)

Comment: thanks for the help, works like a charm! In a similar scenario it works as well `TheirShadow<f64, Output=S>`